# Python - Combinations only if condition applies

Tags: python, math, combinations, combinatorics

Suppose I have a huge list of tuples:

```
tuples = ([1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 2], [25, 73], [1, 3]...)
```

This list has 360000 elements as of now (they are a list of coprimes numbers). I need to make combinations of 3 tuples, such that there are only 3 different numbers on each combination, example:

```
([2, 1], [3, 1], [3, 2])
([2, 1], [5, 1], [5, 2])
```

I need to discard combinations with 4 or more different numbers while generating the list of combinations.

If I try to bruteforce this and test each combination, I end up with `360000 choose 3` which is `7.77 * 10^15`possible combinations to test.

EDIT:
The problem I am trying to solve is:

Find all combinations of coprime pairs in the form:

```
(a, b), (a, c), (b, c)
```

for c < 120000

Steps I've taken:

1. Generate the ternary tree for all Coprime pairs whereboth numbers are less than 120000
2. (ISSUE - Generate the combinations, bruteforcing it won't do)

Comment: How to make combinations only if a certain condition applies (in this case each combination has to have exactly 3 different numbers)

Comment: I've edited the question to add details about the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: If you really have both [1, 2] and [1, 2] as members of your list, then you could cut the list size in half by utilizing they symetry of co-primeness: [1, 2] and [2, 1] are equivalent. Alas, (360000/2) choose 3 is still 9.71E14, so brute-force is still unviable.

Comment: Yes, do that, making sure the smaller of the two is always the first one per pair. Then partition the list by the first value, so you only need to find all `(a,b), (a,c)` combinations. Then check if there is a `(b,c)` for each. I imagine that might be fast enough - can you provide your list for testing?

Comment: A data structure like `{1: [2,3,5,...], 2: [3,5,...], 3: [5,7,...]}` might be helpful for this.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - indeed, very helpful.

Comment: I think "a huge list of tuples" is the wrong way to begin approaching "find all triples that are pairwise relatively prime".

Comment: Thanks guys, the list is unique so [1, 2] and [2, 1] are not present, should have clarified that.

Answer (score 5):

Let's make a dict of sets mapping all *larger* elements to *smaller* elements within a tuple:

```
d = {}
for tup in tuples:
    # here you may limit max(tup) to 120000
    d.setdefault(min(tup), set()).add(max(tup))

# {1: {2, 3}, 2: {3}, 25: {73}}
```

This eliminates also all symetrical pairs: `(1, 2), (2, 1)`.

And then search for all working combinations:

```
for a, bc in d.iteritems():
    for b, c in it.combinations(sorted(bc), 2):
        if b in d and c in d[b]:
            print(a, b, c) # or yield or append to a list
```

Should be faster than your brute force…

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in range(1, 120000):
  for b in range(a+1, 120000):
    if (gcd(a, b) > 1):
      continue;
    for c in range(b+1, 120000):
      if (gcd(a, c) = 1 and gcd(b, c) = 1):
        print (a, b, c)
```

With N = 120000 this takes time roughly N^3/pi^2. A brute force check of all tuples takes time N^6/48, so this is much faster -- about 3 * 10^14 times faster.

Comment: I don't see how you get n^6.  I think all you've gained is a constant factor.

Comment: @Teepeemm: There are binomial(N, 2) pairs and binomial(binomial(N, 2), 3) ~ N^6/48 ways to choose three pairs, so I gain a cubic factor vs. that. eumiro's answer is either cubic or biquadratic, so I certainly don't gain the same factor there.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that generating "a huge list of tuples" is the wrong way to begin approaching "find all triples that are pairwise relatively prime".  Starting by looking at triples is definitely better, so +1.  But I feel like there is a O(n^2) solution lurking out there.

Comment: @Teepeemm: I'm quite sure there isn't, since there are Theta(n^3) triples that work! (It's easy to see that there are more than n^2.99 triples for large n -- just take only the primes.)